# Use PyCharm create a website project, but do not find the db.sqlite3 file

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I use PyCharm create a website project, but do not find the db.sqlite3 file.

[image]

The database settings in `settings.py`:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT**

You see the leftside bar there is no db.sqlite3 file, and I reveal in Finder still can not find it.

Comment: how do you know it isnt found? where is the traceback or what kind of error do you recive? `import os` is written in your settings.py?
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial02/#database-setup

and btw you are building a webiste with django. Pycharm is just an IDE. A powerful IDE but still just an IDE

Answer (score 0):

If there is no db files default, you should execute those command in PyCharm terminal:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Then you can see it.